# How to use realmd in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to join an Active Directory domain?

Tags: active-directory, sssd, ubuntu-14.04, linux

I want to use `realmd` to join an Active Directory domain from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

To do that I just installed `realmd` and some dependencies with this command: `aptitude install realmd sssd sssd-tools samba-common krb5-user`.

After the installation I tried to join my domain with the command `realm --verbose join ad.example.com -U Administrator` it asked for the Administrator password but them crashed with this output:

```
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.ad.example.com
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.7.0.2
 * Successfully discovered: ad.example.com
Password for Administrator: 
 * Unconditionally checking packages
 * Resolving required packages
 * Installing necessary packages: samba-common-bin
 * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.QARGGX -U Administrator ads join ad.example.com
Enter Administrator's password:DNS update failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

Using short domain name -- AD-EXAMPLE
Joined 'REALMD-TEST' to dns domain 'ad.example.com'
No DNS domain configured for realmd-test. Unable to perform DNS Update.
 * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.QARGGX -U Administrator ads keytab create
Enter Administrator's password:
realm: Couldn't join realm: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

After those erros `realmd` does not even work, any command issued with `realmd` returns:

```
realm: Couldn't connect to realm service: Error calling StartServiceByName for 
org.freedesktop.realmd: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildSignaled: 
Process /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper received signal 11
```

The file `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` appears to be created correctly and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` modified accordingly. But this isn't sufficient to successfully join the domain.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem on Debian Jessie. "Signal 11" means a segfault. A segfault is _always_ a bug in the program, so I expect this needs to be reported as a bug and fixed before it can be made to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have outlined all the steps necessary to get this up and working.  There are a series of bugs regarding the install of the packages.  All of the underlying software works great, but there are a few steps you have to take to make things work:  http://funwithlinux.net/2014/04/join-ubuntu-14-04-to-active-directory-domain-using-realmd

**Short version:**

1. Add the following to `/etc/realmd.conf`

   `[service]`
   `automatic-install = no`
2. Next, install the following packages:  samba-common-bin, samba-libs, sssd-tools, krb5-user, adcli
3. Get a kerberos ticket for your AD user.
4. Join in unattended mode with new user principal (on a single line):

**`realm --verbose join localdomain.xx --user-principal=myubuntuserver/DomainAdmin@LOCALDOMAIN.XX --unattended`**

5. The error you mentioned is specifically related to a known bug (at least it's known to Fedora/RH at this time) in sssd.  sssd segfaults on the option **`use_fully_qualified_names = True`** so go ahead and comment out that option and restart sssd.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the accepted answer on 16.04.1 LTS and the command failed with someting about the password. Running `sudo realm join` normally would give the error `Necessary packages are not installed: sssd-tools sssd libnss-sss libpam-sss adcli`, even though they are all installed. After searching for an hour I found [this workaround](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/293540), which says you should add `--install=/` to the join command. So the full syntax is:

```
sudo realm join -v -U administrator DOMAIN.COM --install=/
```